# how to print multiple rows into one row?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table name examResults and subject like following

```
IndexNo  |  AccYear  |  SujectID  |  Mark  |  Grade  

01       |  2014     |  12        |  35    |  C

01       |  2014     |  13        |  64    |  B

02       |  2014     |  12        |  54    |  B
```

Subject Table

```
SujectID   | SubjectNameE  | SubjectNameS

  12       |  English      |  lkdfjlsd

  13       |  Buddhist      |  hkjdfhsd
```

I want to grab the data as bellow

```
IndexNo  |  AccYear |  English  |  Buddhist | Total 

  01     |  2014    |  35 |  C  |   64 | B  |  99
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: try to use join query.. it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

you may need to use the `GROUP_CONCAT` function
See this similar question for reference:
[One table, two column MYSQL query challenge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3082817/one-table-two-column-mysql-query-question)